# Searching for page in site.pages by path without iteration

Tags: jekyll

I have a path to some page from root in Jekyll as a variable `path`.  I want to get some variables from FrontMatter of that page. How could I find this page in `site.pages` without iterating over all pages?
I mean something like

```
{% assign aim = site.pages[path] %}
```

instead of

```
{% for p in site.pages %}
  {% if p.path == path %}
    {% assign aim = p %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Will this solution be faster for a site with a thousand of pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @β.εηοιτ.βε for the hint!

That was what I expected, but when I used this template, I've faced the problem: the output of `{{aim.title}}` was empty.

The `where` filter produces list even it consists of just one element! But each filepath in a file system points exactly at one file, so I expected that `aim` will be the page, not a list.  To fix this, I've added `first` filter:

```
{% assign aim = site.pages | where:"path",path | first %}
```

And now `aim` is the page variable I am searching for.

About speed. This solution builds a site 2X faster on my hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`where`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#where) liquid filter for this:

```
{% assign aim = site.pages | where:"path",path %}
```